# Migration swift to swift 3 NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

When i made the migration swift code i have this error "Type 'Any' has no subscript members" and my code is

```
var myArray: NSMutableArray = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
   let cell = UITableViewCell()
   if let name = self.myArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]["FirstName"] as? String{
      cell.textLabel?.text = ("\(name)")
      }
}
```

I tried many things but i do not have a answer for this problem.

Comment: It seems that you need to tell the compiler that `self.myArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]` is a dictionary (and be allowed to use `["FirstName"]`, accessing it's value for key `FirstName`)?

Comment: Don't use `NSMutableArray`. Use a Swift array.

Comment: try var myArray: Array<Any> ?

Comment: And replace `(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row` with `indexPath.row`. Use Swift types, not old Objective-C types.

Comment: And please [search on an error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Type+%27Any%27+has+no+subscript+members) before posting. This error has been covered many times before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: **Do not use `NSMutableArray` in Swift!**

The error occurs because the compiler needs to know if the object is subscriptable by key. Using a native Swift type solves the problem.

```
var myArray = [[String:Any]]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
   let cell = UITableViewCell() // will not work
   if let name = self.myArray[indexPath.row]["FirstName"] as? String { // optional binding actually not needed
      cell.textLabel?.text = name // please no string interpolation
   }
   return cell // mandatory!
}
```

Note: Consider that `UITableViewCell()` will not work. The recommended way are reusable cells

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
```

Comment: Thank you. this is result :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use

- Generics
- `dequeueReusableCell`
- `IndexPath` instead of `NSIndexPath`

so here's the code

```
import UIKit

class Controller: UITableViewController {

    var persons = [[String:String]]()

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCellID") ?? UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "MyCellID")
        cell.textLabel?.text = persons[indexPath.row]["FirstName"]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: `override` on this method is for `UITableViewController` only. If it's another kind of class which implements the protocol, there is no override here. Also, it's irrelevant for a migration from Swift 1/2 to Swift 3.